# Where does Google Script PropertiesService store data?

Tags: google-apps-script, forms

Where exactly does the Google Script PropertiesService store user property data?

For example, what if I want to clear the user properties without having to run a function with the deleteAllProperties() method?  To phrase it yet another way, is there a way to access Google Script properties from the local browser or OS?

**From Form.html**

```
<input onclick="google.script.run.setProperties(this.parentNode.parentNode);" type="submit" value="Save" >
```

**From Code.gs**

```
function setProperties(form) {
  var filledForm = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("FORM", form);
}
```

Comment: What end result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want two things:  First, I work for a government organization and I may have to answer the question of where the data is stored.  Second, I want to instruct the Service Desk on how to clear the properties manually in case any issues arise from corrupt data.

Comment: Properties *do* get put into the HTML at some point.  You can view the source code in the browser and find user properties.  I'm assuming that the long term storage of the properties is in the Apps Script file itself, as opposed to a cookie.  I highly doubt the data is saved in a cookie, because changing browser settings for cookies, or deleting cookies could break your app, and since the properties are used by add-on developers, Google probably had the foresight to avoid that.  You could easily test that by saving a property, then deleting all the browser cookies, and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, Sandy.  I actually tried setting properties and then deleting cookies and the properties remained, so I don't think the data is stored as either a cookie or application data within the browser.  Still, we're using deduction to figure out where the data is stored while I need a more definitive answer.  I may submit a case with Google Apps for Work on Monday and I will share what I learn here.

Comment: Google replied by saying (I'm paraphrasing), "Sorry, but Apps Script is a developer product and community-based support is your only option."  This is a little disappointing as I'm sure other companies would offer at least an answer to a simple question about their developer products (we would certainly expect Microsoft to be able to answer questions about .NET or Visual Studio).

So!  Anyone else have any thoughts on figuring out EXACTLY where the PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty() method stores its data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google replied, "Properties are stored on the server, and there's no way to delete them locally as you asked on stack overflow since they don't exist locally."

That adequately answers my question.  Thanks to Garrett for going above and beyond to ping Google devs to get this information.

Comment: Good to know. I for certain thought the user properties were persisted in a cookie on local storage.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way of accessing the user properties from PropertiesService, other than by code (as far as i know)

what you see under File>Project Properties>User Properties, are the old deprecated user properties, that have user's global scope, instead of per script scope as the new user properties

Comment: In the meantime `File > Project Properties > User Properties` has been removed.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Script in the Script Editor, go to File>Project Properties>User Properties. From your explanation, I am assuming these are the properties you are trying to delete.

Comment: I don't see that option as of May 2023. There's Project Settings > Script Properties, but nothing about User Properties.